# ConditionalAttribute on Main()

Tags: c#

This is a question out of curiousity. I was messing around with some code, and realized that the following still compiles in release:

```
class Program
{
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    private static void Main()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I thought ConditionalAttribute was supposed to wipe out the method, but it doesn't. What's special about the entry point?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it wipes out the *calls* to the method, not the method itself. `Main` is never (or should never be) called from your code, so this won't change anything.

Comment: Correct. More precisely, I think it's called from `mscoree.dll`?

Comment: Probably, but I don't really know. It's called "by magic". :)